# I can’t configure NTP to work with the GPS module as a synchronization source (NMEA + PPS)

Tags: ubuntu, synchronization, ntp

I can not configure NTP on Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS (Linux 4.15.0-74-generic). As a source of synchronization I want to use NMEA + PPS from GPS module.

GPS module is connected via USB using the SILABS CP2102 interface converter:

```
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 10c4:ea60 Cygnal Integrated Products, Inc. CP210x UART Bridge / myAVR mySmartUSB light
```

A PPS GPS receiver signal is connected to the DCD line of the converter. There are no problems with getting NMEA data and working with them in NTP. A problem has occurred using the PPS signal. I do ldattach PPS / dev / ttyUSB0:

```
[ 1815.641450] pps_ldisc: PPS line discipline registered
[ 1815.641812] pps pps0: new PPS source usbserial2
[ 1815.641820] pps pps0: source "/dev/ttyUSB0" added
```

The corresponding pps0 node appears in / dev. Everything seems to be fine, but it just doesn’t work.

```
ppswatch /dev/pps0
trying PPS source "/dev/pps0"
found PPS source "/dev/pps0"
time_pps_fetch() error -1 (Connection timed out)
time_pps_fetch() error -1 (Connection timed out)
```

Accordingly, NTP does not see the PPS signal. In the kernel, support seems to be included:

```
# HSI clients
#
CONFIG_HSI_CHAR=m
CONFIG_PPS=m
# CONFIG_PPS_DEBUG is not set

#
# PPS clients support
#
# CONFIG_PPS_CLIENT_KTIMER is not set
CONFIG_PPS_CLIENT_LDISC=m
CONFIG_PPS_CLIENT_PARPORT=m
CONFIG_PPS_CLIENT_GPIO=m
```

pps_ldisc after ldattach loaded:

```
lsmod|grep pps
pps_ldisc              16384  1
pps_core               20480  2 pps_ldisc,ptp
```

How to find a problem? Where to looking for?